# How to create cookies on cross domain i have 2 domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am using ajax with PHP
I want to create cookie on ajax calling page
i have tow domain
like
`domain1.com` and `domain2.com`
i have done ajax code on `domain1.com` in page `test1.php`
And Create Cookie on `domain2.com` page `test.php`

test1.php /// domain1.php

```
$.ajax({
         url:domain2.com/test.php,
         type:post,
         datatype:json,
         data:'uname=test',
         success:function(data){
          if(data=='ok'){
                 window.location='http://domain2.com/cookietest.php'
                }
          }
      });
```

test.php ///// domain2.com

```
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
if($uname=='test'){
    setcookie('testcookie',$uname,time()+3600);
    echo 'ok';
}else{
      echo 'not'
     }
```

I checked cookie value on `domain2.com`

cookietest.php ///// domain2.com

```
<?php
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

I did not found created cookie details.
can anyone help me

Comment: not fault of mysql or mysqli

Comment: Thanks. But In this code there have no mysql code.

Comment: yes, but you have put mysql and mysql as tags.

Comment: Can anyone solve my problem ?

Comment: AJAX has same domain policy. Google "CORS".

Comment: what is google CORS ?

Comment: @husaineharaj Under this phrase meant, "Go and search for the term CORS". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Thanks for reply.